# How can I sum multiple time in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

For example, I have multiple times like:

```
$a = "9:00:00";
$b = "8:00:00";
$c = "9:00:00";
```

and so on...

It must return in 26:00:00 but how to subtract it from 45:00:00?

I have to find out total working hours and overtime for my attendance.

Comment: Is it only ever going to be full hours or is there a change you could have `"8:30:00"`?

Answer (score 2):

You can figure out the different using `Carbon`. Need some little trick to add these times. You can do it this way:

```
$a = '09:00:00';
$b = '08:00:00';
$c = '09:00:00';

//convert the $a in carbon instance. 
//convert $b and $c in integer, you can add only integer with carbon. 
$d = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s',$a)->addHours(intval($b))->addHours((intval($c)));

//convert the time "45:00:00" to carbon
$e = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s','45:00:00');

//return the difference
$e->diffInHours($d)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
  $sumSeconds = 0;
  foreach($times as $time) {
      $explodedTime = explode(':', $time);
       $seconds = $explodedTime[0]*3600+$explodedTime[1]*60+$explodedTime[2];
       $sumSeconds += $explodedTime;
  }
  $hours = floor($sumSeconds/3600);
  $minutes = floor(($sumSeconds % 3600)/60);
  $seconds = (($sumSeconds%3600)%60);
  $sumTime = $hours.':'.$minutes.':'.$seconds;
```

This is the code for suming the three times (supposed that they are in array) and the code for subtracting will be almost the same but for the subtraction you will subtract `$sumSeconds` of both times and then convert the result.

Answer (score 0):

Carbon is what you need, it's integrate with laravel by default.

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

using its `addHours()` and `subHours()` function to achieve your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$times = [
  "9:00:00",
  "8:00:00",
  "9:00:00",
];

// Converting the time to seconds makes calculations
// more simple and easier to understand.
function timeToSeconds($time) {
  list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(":", $time);

  return ($hours * 60 * 60) + ($minutes * 60) + $seconds;
}


// Let's use this to convert say 300s into 00:05:00
function formatSecondsAsHMI($seconds) {
  return sprintf(
    '%02d:%02d:%02d',
    floor($seconds / 3600),
    floor($seconds / 60 % 60),
    floor($seconds % 60)
  );
}

// Add an array of times together and return the formatted string hh:mm:ss
function addTimes($times) {
  $seconds = array_sum(array_map(function ($time) {
    return timeToSeconds($time);
  }, $times));

  return formatSecondsAsHMI($seconds);
}

// Subtract an array of times. Order of array important.
// Subtracts 0 from 1 from 2 where 0,1,2 are array keys
// i.e. [03:00:00, 10:00:00] would subtract 3 from 10 = 07:00:00
function subtractTimes($times) {
  $times = array_map(function($time) {
    return timeToSeconds($time);
  }, $times);

  return array_reduce($times, function($carry, $item) {
    return ($item - $carry);
  });
}

// Now just add the times together and subtract the result from 45
echo subtractTimes([addTimes($times), '45:00:00']);
```